# in custom TextInputLayout, setHint() is not working

Tags: android, android-textinputlayout

I am trying to subclass TextInputLayout, in a CustomTextInputLayout. This is the code:

```
public class CustomTextInputLayout extends TextInputLayout {

public CustomTextInputLayout(Context context, AttributeSet attrs) {
    super(context, attrs);
}

public CustomTextInputLayout(Context context, AttributeSet attrs, int defStyleAttr) {
    super(context, attrs, defStyleAttr);
}

public CustomTextInputLayout(Context context) {
    super(context);
}

public View getComponent(){
    return this.getChildAt(0);
}

public void setHint(String hint){
    super.setHint(hint);
}
}
```

I am using it to wrap another custom component, with a button and an EditText:

```
public class ComponentesSeleccion extends RelativeLayout {

private EditText editText;
private Button button;

public ComponentesSeleccion(Context context, AttributeSet attrs, int defStyleAttr) {
    super(context, attrs, defStyleAttr);
}

public ComponentesSeleccion(Context context) {
    super(context);
    inicializar();
}

public ComponentesSeleccion(Context context, AttributeSet attrs) {
    super(context, attrs);
    inicializar();
}

private void inicializar() {
    String infService = Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE;
    LayoutInflater li =
            (LayoutInflater)getContext().getSystemService(infService);
    li.inflate(R.layout.seleccionlayout, this, true);
    editText=(EditText)findViewById(R.id.editText);
    button=(Button)findViewById(R.id.button2);
}

public Button getButton() {
    return button;
}

public EditText getEditText() {
    return editText;
}

public void setInputType(int type){
    editText.setInputType(type);
}

public void setImagen(Drawable drawable){
    button.setBackgroundDrawable(drawable);
}
}
```

With this, I am not able to do in my code:

```
CustomTextInputLayout ctil=(CustomTextInputLayout)view.findViewById(R.id.ctil);
ctil.setHint(“a hint");
```

No exception, no errors, but the hint is not drawn. i can set the normal hint on the EditText, but I want the animated hint of the TextInputLayout.

How could I get it working?

Thank you.

Comment: You mean eliminate my ComponentesSeleccion, and simply add an EditText and a Button in the CustomTextInputLayout? Gonna try that. Thanks for your help.

Comment: I did it, and hint is working, but the button is set below the EditText. I would like it to be set aside of the EditText, that is, in the same "line". Tried to change android:orientation="horizontal" in TextInputLayout, but it is not working.